# Fixing cracked vinyl trim on a front door sidelight

Tags: trim

[image][image]The vinyl trim on my front door sidelight has cracked and separated. I'd like to put it back in place, caulk the joint and paint it. I have not been able to find a good way to reattach it where it has pulled away.

I tried some small brads (you can see holes in the photo) but they don't seem to bite into anything to draw the separated piece in. I also can't find the right kind of clamp with a deep enough opening to glue and clamp it. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'd be looking to understand why it's cracked like that before you try and fix anything. I suspect you have some pressure on the structure.

Comment: Do you know for certain that there's something behind the trim for the brads to fasten to?  Most window assemblies have a 1/4" - 1/2" gap (or larger, depending on the skills of the window framer) between the window frame and the stud.  This is where the shims go to square the window in the RO and is then filled with insulation of some sort.  If the brads are being driven into this gap, there is nothing for them to hold on to.

Comment: That looks like 2 pieces and why is it doing this don’t want to be an alarmist but I have remodeled homes that carpenter ants (or termites) have been the reason for trim popping, window & doors jamming and glass exploding without being touched.

Comment: SteveS - good point about the gap. I think you are correct about nothing there for the brads to hold on to.

Comment: @SteveSh, this appears to be a factory-built sidelight (integrated into an exterior door assembly). It wouldn't have the framing gaps you describe, though there could be other gaps.

Comment: Are you able to post a full-size photo? I'd like to see the cracks in more detail.

Comment: Full pic posted. Both right and left  sidelights have cracked trim. Right sidelight obvious both sides of middle glass pane. Left of door trim also cracked same spot but less obvious. Pic from interior shows location of plastic plugs. Zoom in on that and you'll see that exterior crack is just below plug location. Plug location and exterior crack just below plug are the same for all (4) cracks.